# Could not convert string to float : '100.0000%'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file I am trying to edit.

The code is:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('%', '').astype(float)
```

The values in Column are indeed 100.00% that's why I am trying to get rid of those and keep the number only.
The error is as in the title: could not convert string to float: '100.0000%'

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please show us how is your df looks like more samples so we can reproduce...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works fine for me...

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col=['100.000%']))
df['col'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('%', '').astype(float)
>>> 
    0    100.0
    Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to be because of the .csv format. When I open de df in vs code data shows as "Variable 1", number2, number2, number3 not "Variable1", "number2","number3". The csv is saved as csv utf-8. Any thought?

Comment: open another question... you need to show the file ... or try to look in stack overflow how to treat your csv...

Comment: Data looks like this:
Date,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9
"Date",Campaign 1,GBP,Company General Terms - SB,10949,69,0.6302%,£1.70,£117.13,117.1651%

Comment: cant see the newline...

Comment: Date,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9
[new line]
"Date",Campaign 1,GBP,Company General Terms - SB,10949,69,0.6302%,£1.70,£117.13,117.1651%